# React-styledComponents: Types of property 'children' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, styled-components, react-typescript

I am trying make Reuse-able style-components cards. I used typescript for my React app. I made children type `children?: string | JSX.Element`. But in my card container it got undefined and give typescript error: `Types of property 'children' are incompatible.` even though I made `children optional`. I Really don't get what is main error and how to fix it.

I share my code in [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cards-typescript-5pmyy?file=/src/App.tsx).
`**Ps: It does not thorw errors in codesandbox**`

**This is my card component**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export interface ICardProps {
  title?: string;
  secondaryText?: string;
  hoverable?: boolean;
  thumbnailUrl?: string;
  coverImage?: string;
  url?: string;
  children?: string | JSX.Element;
}

const Container = styled.div<ICardProps>`
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  &:hover {
    ${({ hoverable }) =>
    hoverable
      ? `box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)`
      : null}
  }
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
`;
const SecondaryText = styled.p`
  margin: 0;
  color: #6b6b6b;
`;

const Thumbnail = styled.div<ICardProps>`
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(${({ url }) => url});
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 10px;
`;
const TitleBar = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

const CoverImage = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
`;
const Content = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
`;

const ChildrenContent = styled.div`
  background: pink;
`;

const Card = ({
  title,
  secondaryText,
  thumbnailUrl,
  coverImage,
  children,
  hoverable,
  ...props
}: ICardProps) => {
  return (
    <Container
      {...props}
      {...{ hoverable, title, secondaryText, thumbnailUrl, coverImage, ...props }}>
      {coverImage ? <CoverImage src={coverImage} /> : null}
      <Content>
        <TitleBar>
          {thumbnailUrl ? <Thumbnail url={thumbnailUrl} /> : null}
          <div>
            {title ? <Title>{title}</Title> : null}
            {secondaryText ? <SecondaryText>{secondaryText}</SecondaryText> : null}
          </div>
        </TitleBar>
        {typeof children === `string` ?
          <ChildrenContent> {children}</ChildrenContent> :
          children
        }
      </Content>
    </Container>
  )
};

export default Card;
```

**This is how I am trying to use it**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/macro";
import { Card } from "./lib/Card";

const ThinnerCard = styled(Card)`
  width: 400px;
`;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThinnerCard
        coverImage="http://www.fillmurray.com/500/300"
        thumbnailUrl="http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100"
        title="This is the title"
        secondaryText="Secondary title"
      />

      <Card title="Only a title" secondaryText="And a second text" />

      <Card>
        <h1> Hello I'm a "children" props</h1>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I extends my typescript props like `extendsReact.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>`.

```js
export interface ICardProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  title?: string;
  secondaryText?: string;
  hoverable?: boolean;
  thumbnailUrl?: string;
  coverImage?: string;
  url?: string;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
}



const Card = ({
  title,
  secondaryText,
  thumbnailUrl,
  coverImage,
  hoverable,
  children, 
  ...props
}: ICardProps) => {
  return (
    <Container
      {...props}
      {...{
        hoverable,
        title,
        secondaryText,
        thumbnailUrl,
        coverImage,
        ...props
      }}
    >
      {coverImage ? <CoverImage src={coverImage} /> : null}
      <Content>
        <TitleBar>
          {thumbnailUrl ? <Thumbnail url={thumbnailUrl} /> : null}
          <div>
            {title ? <Title>{title}</Title> : null}
            {secondaryText ? (
              <SecondaryText>{secondaryText}</SecondaryText>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        </TitleBar>
      </Content>
      { children ? (
        <ChildrenContent> {children}</ChildrenContent>
      ) :
        children
      }
    </Container>
  );
};
```